# c++ comparing strings in structure array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, compare, structure

Working on this code where I have an array of account information. I need to write a function where I ask the user to enter a part of a name and it searches the array for it.

More specifically: "Search the structure array for a particular customer’s account. It should accept part of the customer’s name as an argument and then search for an account with a name that matches it. All accounts that match should be displayed (including all customer’s information). If no account matches, a message saying so should be displayed."

I can't seem to compare the functions correctly, I think I'm just approaching this problem incorrectly and would really appreciate some guidance.

Here's the code, I'm working on the function "searchAccount"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Customer
{
    string name;
    string address;
    string city;
    string state;
    int zip;
    string num;
    string date;
    double bal;
};

void readData(Customer []);
void displayData(Customer []);
void changeInfo(Customer []);
void searchAccount(Customer []);


const int MAX = 10;

int main()
{
    int selection;

    Customer data[MAX];

    do
    {
        cout << "Customer Accounts Menu" << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1. Read customer info into array. " << endl;
        cout << "2. Change account information. " << endl;
        cout << "3. Display information in array. " << endl;
        cout << "4. Search for customer account. " << endl;
        cout << "5. Sort customer balances in descending order. " << endl;
        cout << "6. Sort customer names in ascending order. " << endl;
        cout << "7. Compare names of two customers & replace smallest with address of largest" << endl;
        cout << "8. Exit program" << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a selection: " << endl;
        cin >> selection;

        switch (selection)
        {
            case (1):
                readData(data);
                break;

            case (2):
                changeInfo(data);
                break;

            case (3):
                displayData(data);
                break;

            case (4):
                searchAccount(data);
                break;

            case (5):
                break;

            case (6):
                break;

            case (7):
                break;

            default: cout << "Please enter a valid selection." << endl;
        }

    }while(selection != 8);

    return 0;
}

void readData(Customer data[])
{
    int num = 0;

    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("customers.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inFile >> data[num].name >> data[num].address >> data[num].city >> data[num].state >> data[num].zip >> data[num].num >> data[num].date >> data[num].bal;

        while (inFile)
        {
            num++;
            inFile >> data[num].name >> data[num].address >> data[num].city >>  data[num].state >>  data[num].zip >> data[num].num >> data[num].date >> data[num].bal;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
}

void displayData(Customer data[])
{
    for (int num = 0; num < MAX; num++)
    {
        cout << data[num].name << " " << data[num].address << " " << data[num].city << " " << data[num].state << " " << data[num].zip << " " << data[num].num << " " << data[num].date << " " << data[num].bal << endl;
    }
}

void changeInfo(Customer data[])
{
    string name;

    cout << "Enter customer name to change" << endl;
    cin >> name;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (data[i].name == name)
        {
            cout << "Enter new information for " << name << endl;
            cout << "Name: " << endl;
            cin >> data[i].name;
            cout << "Address: " << endl;
            cin >> data[i].address;
            cout << "City: " << endl;
            cin >> data[i].city;
            cout << "State: " << endl;
            cin >> data[i].state;
            cout << "Zip: " << endl;
            cin >> data[i].zip;
            cout << "Phone Number: " << endl;
            cin >> data[i].num;
            cout << "Date of Last Payment: " << endl;
            cin >> data[i].date;
            cout << "Account Balance: " << endl;
            cin >> data[i].bal;
        }
    }
}

void searchAccount(Customer data[])
{
    string name;

    cout << "Enter a name to search: " << endl;
    cin >> name;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, "data[i].name")
        //Not sure what to put here, the function above won't correctly as well
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to provide example, but [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be even better with **M**inimal code.

Answer (score 0):

First, include header that contains algorithms from the standard library:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Then, do the following in your `searchAccount` function:

```
string name;
std::string tempLowercase;

cout << "Enter a name to search: " << endl;
cin >> name;

// Convert entered name to lower case
string enteredLowercase = name;
std::transform(enteredLowercase.begin(), enteredLowercase.end(), enteredLowercase.begin(), ::tolower);

bool found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    // Convert current name to lower case and compare with entered name
    tempLowercase = data[i].name;
    std::transform(tempLowercase.begin(), tempLowercase.end(), tempLowercase.begin(), ::tolower);
    if (std::string::npos != tempLowercase.find(enteredLowercase))
    {
        cout << data[i].name << " " << data[i].address << " " << data[i].city
             << " " << data[i].state << " " << data[i].zip << " " << data[i].num
             << " " << data[i].date << " " << data[i].bal << endl;
        if(!found)
            found = true;
    }
}

if(!found)
    cout << "No customers found" << endl;
```

Comment: This code works, but it doesn't completely satisfy the instructions. All the names are listed like Mike_Jones or Steve_Smith. I should be able to just type in mike or steve and those entries will pop up. I think that's where I need to use the strcmp function but I'm not quite sure

Comment: @HOAX You tagged the question with `c++`. Therefore, I have used `std::string::find` function. Function `strcmp` is C-style function and is not suited for current situation. As far as the instructions go, it clearly says "It should accept part of the customer’s name as an argument and then search for an account with a name that matches it. All accounts that match should be displayed". This is what you have posted in you question, that all accounts whose name contains the entered string should be displayed. I don't understand how does that not satisfy your desired behavior.

Comment: Because if one of the names is Mike_Jones in the array, If I search for just "mike", your code says "no customers found".

Comment: @HOAX Hmm, you are right. I have considered only case sensitive match. I've updated my answer, that should be what you are looking for. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a typical database application, so I'd consider using SQLite in the first place. Standard C++ does not offer this functionality out of the box. However, if you need to stick with plain C++, here's what I think you're looking for:

```
bool found_one = false;
for( int i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
{
  if( data[i].name.find( name ) != std::string::npos )
  {
    found_one = true;
    // output the record
  }
}
if( !found_one )
{
  // output error message
}
```

As a side-note: your code looks a lot more like C than C++. I suggest you consider using std containers, e.g std::vector to store your data.

Comment: This didn't work, added more clarifications to the other comment as well, I'll put them here too: "All the names are listed like Mike_Jones or Steve_Smith. I should be able to just type in mike or steve and those entries will pop up. I think that's where I need to use the strcmp function but I'm not quite sure "